# Pulling data from an xml file to html table

Tags: javascript, html, xml, parsing, web-scraping

Good morning/afternoon

Im a complete newbit with coding, I found a basic code online and modified it to my needs.

I have an XML feed that is refreshed daily for prices and content, what I'm wanting to do is create a table with a description, an image, a price and a "buy here" link.

I have managed to do this but it pulls the whole feed through all 25000+ items, as you can imagine this takes a while to open all the images!

What I'd like to be able to do is specify a specific item to pull the table from.

The page I've got to work is http://www.kimberskitchen.co.uk/full-catalogue-of-products.html what I'd like to do is modify my code so I could select a product and only display that line.

The html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
        table,
        th,
        td {
            border: 5px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        th,
        td {
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <table id="demo"></table>
        <script>
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    myFunction(this);
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://www.kimberskitchen.co.uk/files/theme/datafeed_274439.xml", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            function myFunction(xml) {
                var i;
                var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
                var table = "<tr><th><H1>name</h1></th><th><h1>Price (£)</h1></th><th>    <h1>image</h1></th></tr>";
                var text, parser, xmlDoc;
                var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("prod");
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    table += "<tr><td>" +
                        x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                        "</td><td>" +
                        x[i].getElementsByTagName("buynow")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                        "</td><td align=center><a href = " +
                        x[i].getElementsByTagName("awTrack")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                        "  </a> Click here to buy product</td></tr>";
                }
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure how to modify this, any help is gratefully received.

Comment: Is `http://www.kimberskitchen.co.uk` your own domain? Otherwise, you’re going to run into problems with the Same Origin policy in Ajax.

Comment: yes ,the xml file is saved on the same domain as the page

Comment: Got this working now, just need to work out why the page won't display on iPhone

Comment: Any help on why this won't work on Apple devices?